# LeftBarButtonItem with UISearchBar is not visible on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, ios11

The title is pretty self explanatory, on iOS 10.3 using a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view (in this case `UIStackView`) assigned to a `LeftBarButtonItem` of a NavigationBar is not visible on iOS 11. I haven't figure out why it is not showed but when I type something with the keyboard my logic of the `TextChanged` event works! So the `UISearchView` is there but it is not visible:

[image]

Here is some code (It is coded with C# but it is using Objective C methods.):

```
var width = NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Width;
var height = NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height;
_searchBarContainer = new UIStackView(new CGRect(0, 0, width * 0.75, height))
{
    Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center,
    Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal,
    Spacing = 3
};

_uiSearchBar = new UISearchBar
{
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
    BarTintColor = UIColor.Clear,
    BackgroundImage = new UIImage(),
    Placeholder = Strings.Search
};

_uiSearchBar.SizeToFit();
if (_iOS11)
{
    _uiSearchBar.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(44).Active = true;
}

_searchbarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(_searchBarContainer);

NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(_searchbarButtonItem, true);
ParentViewController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem;
```

Using the same code on iOS 10 this works.

Comment: I havn't really worked with iOS11 yet but I might've remembered seeing something with it disappearing based on the size of the barbuttonitem. Maybe try playing around with the size/frame of it

Comment: @TPN1994 Thank you so much for this comment, this is exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try out setting up constraints to size properly your _searchBarContainer before setting it as the left bar button item. From iOS11 navigations bars use auto layout. Make sure you only add the constraints if iOS 11 is present, I was having problems in iOS 9 navigation bars otherwise. 
Also checkout this thread in the [Dev forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80075) where it's explained how the bar items are wrapped inside stack views, maybe also helps with your particular issue.